# How to make the contents scroll horizontally in mobile/tablet view in html/css

Tags: html, css, scroll, responsive-design

I am working on a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ktw74hp4/24/embedded/result/) in which I want to horizontally scroll the **stripe**, **Global Franchise** and **other images** as present in a line in the fiddle. The **text** above the images should remain fixed in its position.

The snippet of what I want in **mobile view** is shown below. The images should **scroll horizontally** without creating any white space at the right.

[image]

At this moment, the images are fit to screen on mobile but they are compressed so that's the reason why I want to make the contents scrolling in **mobile view** in order to avoid the compression issue.

The CSS codes which I have used in order to fit the images on the screen in a mobile view are:

```
.images {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;


}

.images > div {
      flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
.images img {
  max-width:100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what CSS codes I should add in the fiddle so that images should scroll horizontally without creating any white space at the right with the text being fixed on the top.

Comment: You would most definitely require JavaScript for this. And it sounds like you might benefit from something like Ken Wheeler's [**slick slider**](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

Comment: @ObsidianAge I am wondering if you can give me a pointer how to do that. I have never done this before.

Comment: Well I'm afraid your question is a bit too broad for me to be able to help at this stage. Like you just want an infinitely looping banner rotation? So when an element gets shunted off to the right, it appears back on the far left? Is this permanent, or triggered by the user in some way? And if it's constantly scrolling, wouldn't that make it hard for the user to click on any of the elements?

Comment: Those are very good questions. I have a design which I am trying to replicate. Anything which looks good in the mobile view with the contents getting scroll horizontally will work for me. As you said, yes It will definitely hard for the users, that is the reason why we gonna have gap and specific height (**with some background color**) for those images.  Let me know if you have any more question.

Comment: You can add `white-space` and `overflow` properties for a basic horizontal scroll: https://jsfiddle.net/uzrt8Lj2/

Comment: @sol It looks great. But I want the horizontal scroll in the mobile view till 767 px width I guess.

Comment: You can just remove those properties with a media query

Comment: @sol Sorry for the delay. I want the desktop view to look exactly the same as present in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ktw74hp4/24/embedded/result/). For the mobile view, 
`@media screen and (max-width: 767px)
{

}`, what code do I need to add inside the media queries ? Sorry I am not good with media queries.